# Legal restrictions on minority languages in media and the web

Tags: media, languages, reference-request, comparative-politics, minorities

> The draft law on ensuring the functioning of the Ukrainian language as the national language adopted by the Verkhovna Rada on April 25 obliges all print media to have the Ukrainian version.
>
> According to the document, print media can also be published in other languages provided that the edition is published in the state language simultaneously with the relevant publication in a foreign language, ...
>
> All language versions should be published under the same name, correspond to each other in content, volume and method of printing, and their editions should have the same numbering and be published on one day.
>
> In each place of distribution, print media in the national language must be at least 50% of titles of print media distributed in the same place.
>
> ...the law provides that Internet websites must be first loaded in Ukrainian, but may also have other versions.
> [UNIAN](https://www.unian.info/politics/10530951-ukraine-s-language-bill-obliges-all-print-media-to-have-ukrainian-version.html)

.

> The new legislation requires TV and film distribution firms to ensure 90 percent of their content is in Ukrainian
> [Reuters](https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-ukraine-parliament-language/ukraine-passes-language-law-championed-by-outgoing-president-idUKKCN1S1111)

I am looking for **a study/report on comparable restrictions (enacted in law) on minority languages in countries around the world.**

(The Ukrainian law has other provisions, mentioned in the links, but my question is limited to media and web.)
I ran across [OSCE Guidelines on the use of Minority Languages in the Broadcast Media](https://www.osce.org/hcnm/32310?download=true) but it does not say much about specific countries.

Comment: I've removed the ukraine tag because I've seen more experienced users remove country tags from comparative politics questions when the question is not asking about any more details on the country that motivated the question. (There's also a 5 tag limit, and the other tags are less arguable.)

Answer (score 1):

France had some history of that. Here is the overview in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_policy_in_France).

Other EU states dabated it, like Germany, but I'm not sure if anything like that was enacted. There would be a difference between print publications and broadcast media -- anything involving terrestrial frequencies would bring restrictions as to the maximum percentage of commercials, minimum percentage of news, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. There are restrictions in Quebec: "Advertising in non-French media can be just in the language of the media. For example, a commercial on an English television channel can be in English only, and an ad appearing in an Italian newspaper can be in Italian only", which might be considered a penalty on minority language publications in Quebec, although French is a minority language in Canada.